# String storage and Comparison in Linked List

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list

Here is my code but it seems that the storage of the string into the variable in the linked list is not working. May I ask what the problem is and how to fix it. Thank you.

```
typedef struct studList {
    char studName[3];
    struct studList *next;
} stud;

typedef struct courseList { 
    char courseName[3];
    stud *toStud;
    struct courseList *next;
} course;

int compareStuds(stud *toStud1, stud *toStud2) {
    int count = 0;
    stud *tempPtr;
    while(toStud1 != NULL) {
        tempPtr = toStud2;
        while(tempPtr != NULL) {
            if(strcmp(toStud1->studName, tempPtr->studName) == 0) {
                count = 1;
            }
            tempPtr = tempPtr->next;
        }
        toStud1 = toStud1->next;
    }
    return count;
}

int main (void)
{
    course *chead = NULL, *cnode, *hptr = NULL, *hptr2 = NULL;
    stud *shead = NULL, *snode = NULL;
    int noc,i,x,y,row,col,matrix[50][50],z,a = 0;
    printf("Enter the number of course(s): ");
    scanf("%d", &noc);
    printf("Enter 3 letter course name followed by 3 letter student names separated by spaces.\n");

    for(i = 0; i < noc; i++){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
        scanf(" %100[^\n]%*c",in);
        while(in[z] != NULL){
            if(x == 0){
                cnode = (course *) malloc(sizeof(course));
            }
            if(in[z] != ' ' && x < 3){
                cnode->courseName[x] = in[z];
                x++;
            }
            else if(in[z] != ' '){
                if(y == 0){
                    snode = (stud *) malloc(sizeof(stud));
                }
                if(y < 3){
                    snode->studName[y] = in[z];
                    y++;
                }
            }
            if(y == 3){
                cnode->toStud = snode;
                shead = snode->next;
                snode = shead;
                y = 0;
            }
            z++;
        }
        chead = cnode->next;
        cnode = chead;
    }
    hptr = chead;
    for(i = 0; i < noc; i++)
        matrix[i][i] = 0;
    for(row = 0; hptr != NULL; row++){
        hptr2 = hptr->next;
        col = row + 1;
        for(;hptr2 != NULL; col++){
            matrix[row][col] = compareStuds(hptr->toStud, hptr2->toStud);
            matrix[col][row] = compareStuds(hptr->toStud, hptr2->toStud);
            hptr2 = hptr2->next;
        }
        hptr = hptr->next;
    }
    for(row = 0; row < noc; row++){
        for(col = 0; col < noc; col++){
            printf("%d ", matrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code basically outputs a matrix if there is a similar student in a course. If same students exist it is flagged by a 1. I can't seem to make the storage of the course name and students in the linked list since you need a student linked list for each course. and there is a lot of course linked list depending on the user. Any ideas?

Input would be like:

Enter number of course: 5

```
c01 qwe wer ert rty tyu
c02 asd sdf dfg fgh ghj hjk
c03 aaa zzz xxx sss www
c04 qwe aaa dfg  poi lll
c05 asd ppp lll mmm

0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
```

Note: The matrix is represented by the course from 1 to n num of courses.

like below,

```
 c01 c02 c03 c04 c05
c01 0   0   0   1   0
c02 0   0   0   1   1
c03 0   0   0   1   0
c04 1   1   1   0   1
c05 0   1   0   1   0
```

If there is a student in the same class it is marked with a 1, if not then 0. since c01 and c04 both have 'qwe' in them then row c04 and col c01 is marked with 1 the same as row c01 and col c04 is marked also with 1.

Comment: What is the variable `in`?

Comment: Also, you have to remember that strings contain an extra special character (`'\0'`) that tells the system where the strings end. So for a three-character string you actually need *four* characters.

Comment: And finally, [don't cast the return of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Comment: in is just a temporary variable to store the whole input string to allocate each character to be either a course or a student. The first 3 characters of in are added to the course struct and the following characters by 3 are added to the student struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you store strings of three characters in arrays with space for three characters. The problem with this is that in C strings don't have a length, and functions like `strcmp` expects all strings to be terminated with a special character, the so called null character (not to be confused with the `NULL` pointer). This special character is normally expressed as `'\0'`.

What you need to do is to increase all string arrays to make space for this terminator character, and the add it to the end of the strings. Like in `char studName[4];` and e.g.

```
if(y < 3) {
    snode->studName[y++] = in[z];
} else if (y == 3) {
    snode->studName[y] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: If you use studName[3], that means you have 4 slots to put a character in. Is that not enough? And even though I've increased the string arrays the output I'm getting is also wrong. I think the problem lies in the organization of the linked list

Comment: @Marquack No that's three slots, numbered zero to two.